# Default proximity search in solr

Tags: search, solr, proximity

I was wondering if there is anyway to set up a default search proximity within solr via the solrconfig.xml.

Currently, if I want to perform a proximity search I would have to do the following:

```
q="red cars"~10
```

Is there a way to set the 10 word proximity by default so that all queries are proximity searches with a 10 word proximity range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [eDismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax), you set the proximity as default slop.
The proximity would be enabled by default as the search would look for words that are slop distance apart.

Check [Query Phrase Slop](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qs_.28Query_Phrase_Slop.29) and [Phrase slop](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#ps_.28Phrase_Slop.29) which will set the slop for the queries.
Query Phrase Slop is applied to Phrase Queries.
While, Phrase slop will be applied to normal queries.

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <str name="qf">field</str>
        <str name="qs">10</str>
        <str name="pf">field</str>
        <str name="ps">10</str>
        <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```